# django allauth only one email per user

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-allauth

With the django-all-auth default templates / views, the user can have several email address (with only one primary) I'd like to force the user to have only one email address, how can I do that please?

Comment: No answer, but check out https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1109